# XAMPP Apache with multiple SSL hosts issue

Tags: php, apache, ssl

I am attempting to run two SSL hosts for two separate sites on the same local server.

It works fine with one

http-ssl.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerName drupal.local
 DocumentRoot C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\code\drupal
 SSLEngine on
 SSLCertificateFile C:\xampp\apache\conf\ssl.crt\server.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile C:\xampp\apache\conf\ssl.key\server.key
</VirtualHost>
```

however when I add another host I get the following errors in the apache error log

```
[Mon Jul 06 15:26:19.768431 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 10672:tid 260] AH01909: anchor.local:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Jul 06 15:26:19.768431 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 10672:tid 260] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Jul 06 15:26:19.818431 2015] [core:warn] [pid 10672:tid 260] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Mon Jul 06 15:26:19.978431 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 10672:tid 260] AH01909: anchor.local:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Jul 06 15:26:19.978431 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 10672:tid 260] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Jul 06 15:26:20.008431 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10672:tid 260] AH00455: Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1l PHP/5.6.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 06 15:26:20.008431 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10672:tid 260] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jan 28 2015 16:48:40
[Mon Jul 06 15:26:20.008431 2015] [core:notice] [pid 10672:tid 260] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Mon Jul 06 15:26:20.018431 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10672:tid 260] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 7984
[Mon Jul 06 15:26:20.728431 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 7984:tid 272] AH01909: anchor.local:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Jul 06 15:26:20.728431 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 7984:tid 272] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Jul 06 15:26:20.938431 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 7984:tid 272] AH01909: anchor.local:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Jul 06 15:26:20.938431 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 7984:tid 272] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Jul 06 15:26:20.968431 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7984:tid 272] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

The config which fires the errors look like

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerName anchor.local
 DocumentRoot C:\xampp\htdocs\anchor-2.6.4\code\drupal
 SSLEngine on
 SSLCertificateFile C:\xampp\apache\conf\ssl.crt\server.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile C:\xampp\apache\conf\ssl.key\server.key
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerName test.local
 DocumentRoot C:\xampp\htdocs\code\
 SSLEngine on
 SSLCertificateFile C:\xampp\apache\conf\ssl.crt\server.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile C:\xampp\apache\conf\ssl.key\server.key
 </VirtualHost>
```

I have tried running it SSL on different ports but nothing as of yet.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried matching the ssl ids to the server id?

Comment: That Did it! add it as an answer and I will accept it. Regards,

Comment: great just added an answer so people can find it more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that the server id and the SSL ID are the same.

Comment: Thank you very much fro your time... to other people struggling with this issue look up "Name based virtual hosts"